# Is this possible in php $var = include 'page.php' . "data";

Tags: php

Is this possible to store other php code inside a variable.
I am trying to create php page from backend as same in CMS

```
$var = include 'page.php' . "
php code start

$code = include 'bootstrap.php' . "
// header code
     php code                 
 } 
// footer code               
";
    $menu_alias = "newHTMLFileName";
    $path= "../folder".$menu_alias.".php";
    if (!file_exists ($path))
    {

        $handle = fopen ($path, "w");
        $write = fwrite ($handle, $code);
        fclose($handle);
        echo "created";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "already created";
    }
```

I want to know if it is this possible to write PHP code and MySQL query and store both to a variable.
Thanks in advance

Comment: why the `javascript` tag?

Comment: you can do something like `$var = 'page.php' ` and then `include $var`